# Stack Exchange SQL dumps don't contain answers?

Tags: support, data-dump

Stack Exchange provides database dumps on [this link](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange).

However, the structure of files don't contain answers. It has only: *Badges*, *Comments*, *PostLinks*, *PostHistory*, *Posts*, *Tags*, *Users*, and *Votes*.

In the *Posts* I can see column *AcceptedAnswerId*, which is a relation to the *Answer*, but I can't see a table of answers.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out myself. The `Post` may be either type `1` which is a question or a type `2` which is an answer.